# Append files array to Form Data

Tags: php, arrays, form-data

I have and array files like so:

```
 Array (4)
 File {name: "1.jpg", lastModifiedDate: Thu Jun 16 2016 16:12:00 GMT+0200 (CEST), size: 76669, type: "image/jpeg", slice: function}
 File {name: "2.jpg", lastModifiedDate: Thu Jun 16 2016 16:12:00 GMT+0200 (CEST), size: 85341, type: "image/jpeg", slice: function}
 File {name: "3.jpg", lastModifiedDate: Thu Jun 16 2016 16:12:00 GMT+0200 (CEST), size: 46841, type: "image/jpeg", slice: function}
 File {name: "4.jpg", lastModifiedDate: Thu Jun 16 2016 16:12:00 GMT+0200 (CEST), size: 89657, type: "image/jpeg", slice: function}
```

Can I not just append this array to a FormData Object and then send it to my php script to process?

for example:

```
data.append("files[]", files_to_upload);
```

Or do I have to loop through the files array and append each file separately?

Comment: Should be available in your PHP as `$_FILES`: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php

Answer (score 1):

Ok, found it out.

```
// append files to the form data
for(var i=0; i<files_to_upload.length; i++){
    data.append("files[]", files_to_upload[i]);
}
```

just had to loop through the files array and append them one by one.
the can access them nicely as usual via $_FILES

cheers